# Use information out of "OnProgressUpdate" in AsyncTask(Android) in my Main Thread

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

i am using an AsyncTask that is listening to a server and makes an publishProgess(receivedMessage) every time a message is received, so i save the specific message in a field "ArrayList messageStrings;".

Now i want to access that "messageStrings"-Arraylist from Outside of that AsyncTask-class, but of course i get an "concurrentmodificationexception"-Error.

I have tried to "synchronize" all functions that use it, but i won't help.

So how do i handle messages out of an AsyncTask properly?

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;    
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class ReadInStream extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object>  {
Socket socket;
public ArrayList<String> stringList;
//Socket der Verbindung
public ReadInStream(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Thread ReadInStream started.");
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            // jede Zeile einlesen und überprüfen, ob sie etwas enthaelt
            String inputLine = inStream.readLine();
            if (inputLine != null && inputLine.trim() != ""
                    && inputLine.length() > 0) {

                System.out.println("Recieved: " + inputLine);
                publishProgress(inputLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
    return "";
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
       stringList.add(values[0]);

}

public synchronized ArrayList<String> getStringList(){
    return this.stringList;
}
```

}

---

Where i call it:

```
    commandList = serverConnection.readIn.getStringList();
    for(String item: commandList){
       if (item.startsWith("71 53 11 40")){
           CofKleinEsp = Integer.decode(item.substring(12));
           System.out.println(CofKleinEsp);
           commandList.remove(item);}
```

Comment: can you share part of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry, i hope this helps.

Comment: you can declare your ArrayList as volatile and use synchronized blocks when you are modifying list... you will get ConcurrentModificationException only when you are using iterator on list...

Comment: but what should i use as a lock for the synchronized blocks?

Comment: the ArrayList object...

Comment: `volatile` does nothing at all. It would only help if a background thread would assign a new `ArrayList` to your `stringList` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConcurrentModificationException` is not related to that `AsyncTask`. `onProgressUpdate` is called within the Ui thread and it does not share any mutable state with `doInBackground`. You need no synchronization if nothing but the ui thread touches `stringList`.

Your problem is

```
    for (String item : commandList) {
        commandList.remove(item);
    }
```

You modify the list while you iterate over it. That is a concurrent modification as well. To solve that, use the `Iterator` to remove items. That way the iterator (used implicitly above as well) will know when an element is removed and will not complain any more.

```
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = commandList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String item = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

The second option you have is to use an indexed loop and traverse the list from behind.

```
    for (int i = commandList.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        commandList.remove(i);
    }
```

You could do it from start to finish as well but you will have to deal with changing indexes then. Once you delete `i` your next iteration must handle `i` again since everything was shifted one towards the start.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
public volatile ArrayList<String> stringList;
```

and

```
commandList = serverConnection.readIn.getStringList();
synchronized (commandList) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = commandList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String string = (String) iterator.next();
            if(string.startsWith("71 53 11 40")) {
                 CofKleinEsp = Integer.decode(item.substring(12));
                 System.out.println(CofKleinEsp);
                 iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Threads may  create a local inner copy of variables if they are non volatile. volatile indicates the Threads that don't create local inner copy...

Comment: Threads may cache the object referenced by a variable instead of reading it everytime you use a variable in your code. `volatile` guarantees that other threads can see changes made to that variable (they must refresh the value every time now). E.g. in this example if a thread assigns a whole different `ArrayList` to `stringList`. But nothing ever changes the object that `stringList` refers to so `volatile` results in nothing but synchronization overhead. Changes to the content of the `ArrayList` also don't inherit the `volatile` property of the variable that is referencing their "container".